# How to make a checkbox checked based on its parent div clicked inside ngFor?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a list of checkboxes inside ngFor. Each checkbox has its own parent div. I want checkboxes to be checked once the div clicked.

Here is my code.

```
<div *ngFor="let option of qustions; let i = index" (click)="doCheckboxCheck()">
  <input type="checkbox" [value]="option.value">
  <span>Checkbox {{i}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assign an Angular [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables#syntax) to the `<input>` element and toggle it's `checked` property in the `<div>`'s `click` or `mouseup` event.

Now this could modify the default behavior of checkbox's own click event, so you could bind the `[checked]` toggle to `<input>` too.

```html
<div 
  class="checkbox-container" 
  *ngFor="let option of questions; let i = index"
  (mouseup)="inputCheckbox.checked = !inputCheckbox.checked"
>
  <input
    #inputCheckbox
    class="checkbox"
    type="checkbox"
    [value]="option.value"
    (mouseup)="inputCheckbox.checked = !inputCheckbox.checked"
  >
  <span>Checkbox {{ option.value }}</span>
</div>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gbhm4z?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

We can change the state of the checkbox on div click by passing the index to the even handler. Please refer to the link below which is having a working solution,

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  questions = [
    { value: "Checkbox-1", checked: false },
    { value: "Checkbox-2", checked: false },
    { value: "Checkbox-3", checked: false },
    { value: "Checkbox-4", checked: false },
    { value: "Checkbox-5", checked: false }
  ];

  doCheckboxCheck(index: number): void {
     this.questions[index].checked = !this.questions[index].checked;
  }
}

Template:

<div *ngFor="let option of questions; let i = index" (click)="doCheckboxCheck(i)">
  <input type="checkbox" [value]="option.value" [checked]="option.checked">
  <span>Checkbox {{i}}</span>
</div>
```

editor url - https://stackblitz.com/edit/checkbox-click?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Additional tip: replace `this.questions[index].checked = true;` with `this.questions[index].checked = !this.questions[index].checked;` to make the function work like a toggle button.